# Side nav doesn't work on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, materialized

Side nav works fine, but when I click on any button on it auto scroll isn't working. all links are not working.

```html
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="white" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper" style="width: 90%;margin: 0 auto;">
      <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/fortuna_logo_black.png"></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#solution">Our Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#forme">Is this for Me?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#priceing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="sidenav">
        <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#solution">Our Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#forme">Is this for Me?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#priceing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you update your question with the CSS, I guess you are using more CSS than provided above. Are you also using Javascript or only CSS?

With the information that you provide in your question, we can't really do much as we cant see the problem.